# Sync a local shared network folder to a SharePoint Document library

Tags: sync, onedrive

We have a local shared folder used by HR department mapped as `M:\HR\docs`
We would like to sync that folder to the

```
https://mygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/hr/docs
```

on order that any changes on local network drive be synked with the sharepoint folder, sharepoint site users should be able to find latest documents put on `M:\HR\docs` drive.

What is the procedure? The file/folder modification history and the user rights should not be alterated, kepp as in source.

I saw there is a way to sync manually via FME to SharePoint; but how to keep files synked, maybe via OneDrive shortcuts or something similar?